# Material UI pagination component initial view of number override the default

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the Material UI the pagination component is shown below.

```
  <Pagination count={10} />
```

[image: Material Ui Pagination]

Here the pagination starts from 1 and first view ends at 5, I need to show 1 to 4 as shown below

I tried using the siblingCount and boundaryCount, but that didn't work. Is there way or am I missing something in the above prop.

[image: Limit till 4]

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to do this.

This is controlled by the following block of code (from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Pagination/usePagination.js#L57):

```
  const siblingsEnd = Math.min(
    Math.max(
      // Natural end
      page + siblingCount,
      // Upper boundary when page is low
      boundaryCount + siblingCount * 2 + 2,
    ),
    // Less than endPages
    endPages[0] - 2,
  );
```

When `page`, `boundaryCount`, and `siblingCount` are all 1, `siblingsEnd` will be 5 (because of `boundaryCount + siblingCount * 2 + 2`). If you use a `siblingCount` of 0, you get a `siblingsEnd` of 3, but this causes it to behave in a way that doesn't look as nice when you start progressing to later pages. There isn't a way currently to have the first block of numbers end at 4 when `page` is 1.

Comment: You could create your own copy of the code, but I think this will be a bit tricky to change without introducing other issues due to the interplay between this logic and the ellipsis logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so there is no way isn't or can we update the code and use it ? i checked this file how can i update the logic which can work in the above case as mentioned in the question?

Comment: The component was solving the issue and it really supports well but this use case i was not able to solve

Comment: If you see this library https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/CPagination/ it have this 4, but i was using material ui for this components, For this feature i need to do more customization and need to introduce another set of package,  let me know if you have any idea on this it will be a great help